# Pandas: create a new column based on percentage growth rates from another column

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance

I am pretty sure I am struggling with something very simple, but I need some help...

I am trying o add in the column `Portfolio` the total values of shares based on their daily price development:

| Date | Close | Change | Portfolio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-12-27 | 10381.509766 | NaN | 1000.000000 |
| 2018-12-28 | 10558.959961 | 0.017093 | 1017.092908 |
| 2019-01-02 | 10580.190430 | 0.002011 | 1002.010659 |
| 2019-01-03 | 10416.660156 | -0.015456 | 984.543731 |
| 2019-01-04 | 10767.690430 | 0.033699 | 1033.698927 |

I am using therefore the following function:

```
def XP_strategy(data):
    #Starting capital
    START = 1000
    data['Change'] = data['Close'].pct_change()
    data['Portfolio'] = START
    data.loc[1:, 'Portfolio'] = data['Portfolio'].shift(1) * (1 + data['Change'])

    columns = ['Close', 'Change', 'Portfolio']

    return data[columns]
```

As you can see I am not able to aply the formula for a Portfolio ion a day based on the day before. Is there someone who could help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other answers in this thread are technically correct and return your expected output - but if you're trying to calculate shares values - that's wrong. On simpler numbers - if you bought 10 shares $100 each, and after some time each share is worth $1000, your portfolio should be 10x bigger. That won't be the case with the method you proposed.

I would go about this in an easier way - you just need to establish a proportion *portfolio* / *close* once (AKA number of shares owned), and then use the proportion to figure out the *portfolio* value from a given *close* value. Like this:

```
start = 1000
proportion = start/df['Close'].iloc[0]
df['Portfolio'] = proportion * df['Close']
```

Result:

```
         Date         Close           Portfolio
0  2018-12-27   10381.509766        1000.000000
1  2018-12-28   10558.959961        1017.092908
2  2019-01-02   10580.190430        1019.137935
3  2019-01-03   10416.660156        1003.385865
4  2019-01-04   10767.690430        1037.198892
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pct_change`

```
START = 1000
df['Portfolio'] = START + START * df['Close'].pct_change().fillna(0)
print(df)

# Output:
         Date         Close    Change    Portfolio
0  2018-12-27  10381.509766       NaN  1000.000000
1  2018-12-28  10558.959961  0.017093  1017.092908
2  2019-01-02  10580.190430  0.002011  1002.010659
3  2019-01-03  10416.660156 -0.015456   984.543731
4  2019-01-04  10767.690430  0.033699  1033.698927
```